# Should I use useMemo with React Native Webview?

Tags: react-native

Let's say I have a WebView and it's loading a fixed HTML string like:

```
const html = "<html>....</html>"
<AutoHeightWebView source={{html:html}} />
```

Would that be necessary to wrap it inside `useMemo` so the component doesn't get re-rendered more than necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on if `html` changes at all. If it doesn't, you may as well create a constants file outside the component and utilize it from there.

`useMemo` memoizes values dependant on certain state/dependency changes ([React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)). Therefore if `html` does not change based on some other state/dependency changes, I don't think its necessary to wrap it in a `useMemo`.

However, you won't see any performance degradation/negative side-effects if you did wrap `html` in a `useMemo`.

Comment: Thanks. `html` doesn't change.

Comment: In that case, don't use `useMemo` :)